# Android In App Billing Minimum Price

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am trying to create an in-app product for my app with a price of $0.25.  Per https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&&answer=1153485, I should be able to do that, but I cannot create anything less than $0.99.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: visit http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412?hl=en to see minimum and maximum prices

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to: https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/bin/answer.py?answer=138412 you cannot.

Comment: I don't see any prices here. I checked the other links as well, but I didn't find anything about minimum prices.

Answer (score 8):

this is table for price brackets country wise:https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286